# Is this integration test or unit test? (testing rest controller in spring)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I write tests for my rest controller in spring. And I have two questions.

1. Is this integration test or unit test?

2. Should I test here validation annotations like `@NotNull` and `@Valid` and other? If no, how to disable them? Because when I pass incorrect json to post request these annotations by default will give me bad request error in response.


External dependencies like services are mocked and class has `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = UserController.class, secure = false)` 
annotations.

```
@Test
void findByUsername_returnUser() throws Exception {
    when(userService.findByUsername(USERNAME)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(user));
    when(converterContext.getConverter(ConverterShowUserDto.class)).thenReturn(converterShowUserDto);
    when(converterShowUserDto.convert(user)).thenReturn(showUserDto);
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user?username=" + USERNAME))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status()
                    .isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.username", is(USERNAME)));
}
```

My example controller method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getById(@PathVariable(value = "id") @ExistAccountWithId int id) {
    Optional<User> user = userService.findById(id);
    ShowUserDto showUserDto = convert(user.get());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(showUserDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Validation is based only on custom annotations and exceptions are caught globally. So I dont have any validation inside controller methods. They are separated from each other.

Comment: Why does it matter what you call it? You're *integrating* some parts (e.g. the Spring wiring with your own controller class methods), but testing the controller as a single *unit* as its collaborators are all mocked out. And you should test any functionality you rely on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe @pvpkiran Hmmm so when I test controller as a single unit should I test validation too? Many methods can has the same annotations so I think it is bad to make tests like `verifyAccount_usernameIsNull_error400` and `registerAccount_usernameIsNull_error400` and more.  Especially when I catch validation errors and exceptions globally. Not in controller methods

Comment: But if you don't test that functionality, where is it getting tested? What catches a regression if you refactor it or change something related? It's probably more helpful to think about *why* you're writing these tests than what to describe them as.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I will test every case of validation  as a part of controller tests I will have about 10 tests or more on one method. Because I have to check that every field is not null, is not empty, has correct pattern (email), is already in database (username/email, registration) and many others things to which I use annotations. Maybe it is correct way, but I think it is not best way to test them in controller layer. I can test them separately

Answer (score 3):

> Is this integration test or unit test?

This is unit test. Here you are testing your controller. But it is slightly more than unit test I would say. Because you are testing not only your controller file(UserController), but the controller layer of spring(`@WebMvcTest(...)`).

> Should I test here validation annotations like @NotNull and @Valid
>   and other? If no, how to disable them? Because when I pass incorrect
>   json to post request these annotations by default will give me bad
>   request error in response.

Yes you have to(Or rather you can). That is what I meant, here you can test not only the contoller file, but the controller layer.  You can disable this if you want by registering a mockvalidator.

> External dependencies like services are mocked and class has

hence it is not an integration test.

Comment: What is more correct way? Test controller layer with validation annotations or just controller file and disable validation? In the second case I would to test them separately. Can you edit your answer and show me how to disable them? Because it doesn't work when I add `@MockBean(name="mvcValidator") private Validator mockValidator;`. I have found this method but nothing change then.

Comment: I would say don't disable validator, it is part of your controller layer. It is better to test with various data and assert for exceptions. What I mean is, try sending valid data and invalid data and test you get exception

Comment: I have edited my question. Should i still test controller like this with enabled validator?